# How do I ensure lrint is inlined in gcc?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, c99

After reading around the subject, there is overwhelming evidence from numerous sources that using standard C or C++ casts to convert from floating point to integer numbers on Intel is very slow. In order to meeting the ANSI/ISO specification, Intel CPUs need to execute a large number of instructions including those needed to switch the rounding mode of the FPU hardware.

There are a number of workarounds described in various documents, but the cleanest and most portable seems to be the lrint() call added to C99 and C++ 0x standards. Many documents say that a compiler should inline expand these functions when optimization is enabled, leading to code which is faster than a conventional cast, or a function call.

I even found references to gcc feature tracking bags to add this inline expansion to the gcc optimizer, but in my own performance tests I have been unable to get it to work. All my attempts show lrint performance to be much slower than a simple C or C++ style cast. Examining the assembly output of the compiler, and disassembling the compiled objects always shows an explicit call to an external lrint() or lrintf() function.

The gcc versions I have been working with are 4.4.3 and 4.6.1, and I have tried a number of flag combinations on 32bit and 64bit x86 targets, including options to explicitly enable SSE.

How do I get gcc to inline expand lrint, and give me fast conversions?

Comment: Have you actually profiled and confirmed that using the obvious cast is taking a significant amount of your program's runtime?

Comment: Profiling shows that I can get a 2-4% speed difference using a hand written assembler macro lifted from an article. This is worthwhile as the computation is being done between frames of a 3D rendering application.

Comment: did you set `-fno-math-errno`? you should also consider using `-ffast-math`, which is not always an option if you rely on specific fp-semantics...

Comment: -fno-math-errno turns out to do the trick! Thanks Christoph. Feel free to put that in as the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `lrint()` function may raise domain and range errors. One possible way the libc deals with such errors is setting `errno` (see C99/C11 section 7.12.1). The overhead of the error checking can be quite significant and in this particular case seems to be enough for the optimizer to decide against inlining.

The gcc flag `-fno-math-errno` (which is part of `-ffast-math`) will disable these checks. It might be a good idea to look into `-ffast-math` if you do not rely on standards-compliant handling of floating-point semantics, in particular NaNs and infinities...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `-finline-functions` flag to gcc.

You can also direct GCC to try to integrate all “simple enough” functions into their callers with the option `-finline-functions.`

see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html

Here you can say gcc to make all function to inline but not all will be inlined. 
 The compiler uses some heuristics to determine whether the function is small enough to be inlined. One more thing is that a *recursive function* are also not going to be inline here.

Comment: I have tried -finline-functions and it made no difference to the compiler output.

Comment: if you are using lrint() of math library in your code and compiling it by gcc then lrint()  will not be inlined because in your case it will be comes from binary linked library. code of lrint()  is not going to inlined here

Comment: This document indicates otherwise: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html

"The ISO C99 functions ..... lrintf, lrintl, lrint ...... are handled as built-in functions except in strict ISO C90 mode (-ansi or -std=c90)."

Further up the document it says: "Many of these functions are only optimized in certain cases; if they are not optimized in a particular case, a call to the library function will be emitted." but I have been unable to work out a case in which they are optimized.